# Xamarin; Android 11.0 SDK is not available in Visual Studio; Target Framework

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

In a computer, I have installed Android 11.0 SDK for a Visual Studio 2019 Community installation and my Xamarin Android app is compiled correctly using this SDK. The SDK was installed automatically:
[image]

Then I installed Visual Studio 2019 Community in another computer to compile my app there. But it seems the Android 11.0 SDK is no longer available:

[image]

It is not installed automatically and I cannot find anywhere to install it manually. What's wrong and how can I install Android 11.0 SDK on Visual Studio?

Comment: Update the  VS to the latest version and check again .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT It was installed from internet and so it is the latest...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now Android 11 is not officially supported in Visual Studio.

So you have two options:

- Select to use unofficial repositories in that dialog
- Wait for the version 16.9 where it is supposed to be supported.

Comment: Yes there is an option called "unsupported repository" open in Android SDK and Tools dialog.

Answer (score 1):

After long searching and none of the solutions were working for me, i've found that the SDK can also be installed with the VS Installer.
The API level 30 (Android 11) was nowhere to be found to install, nor VS SDK Manager nor Android Studio SDK Manager (the AS SDK Manager didn't even work, could not load any SDK's)

(See screenshots)
Go to VS Installer -> Modify VS version
-> Go to tab 'Individual Components' -> Search for SDK API level 30 -> Select and install

After the first login you'll probably need to accept SDK licenses again as I had to.

Hope this helps anyone who, like me, did not find any other solution working
PS: I did update VS to its latest version before doing this, not sure if this is mandatory or not since I was on 16.10 before but if this doesn't work, try updating VS itself first.

[image: VS Installer home]

[image: VS Installer individual component]